# how to backup your mamp pro mysql dbs?

Tags: mysql, mamp, backup-strategies

while I find the apache portion of mamp pretty easy to backup, what is everyone using or how are you performing a scheduled backup of your mysql databases? It would be kinda annoying to export each DB one by one.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
/MAMP/Libray/bin/mysqldump
```

You can add it to your path if you want to make it easier for your cron jobs.

Comment: As a total noob, could someone explain how I use this in a little more detail? I have no clue where to go from here...

Answer (score 1):

$mysqldump --all-databases > mysql_dump.sql

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple cron that would export all the databases you wish using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) and then move them to a remote machine for storage using scp or some other mechanism.

Comment: i tried that, however, either my script was wrong or it could not connect to mamp, it could not locate the mysqldump command

Comment: Try installing macports and install mysqldump from the repository. Would need to check to see that the versions will be compatible though. I'm sorry but I don't use Mamp, I have installed everything either from macports or by hand.